# iOS post json data to web service and return result

Tags: c#, ios, json, wcf, afnetworking

I've got WCF web service which takes email address and returns "True" if that entry doesn't exist in the database or "False" if it exists.When i used fiddler and POST data to service it returns result as expected, when i try to send request from my iPad app it just say "Invalid JSON primitive: Email.".

Service link:
http://www.unluapps.com/Service1.svc/CheckRejected

JSON for testing:

```
{"Email":"test@unluco.com"}
```

Ios Code:

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   NSError *e = nil;
   NSDictionary *parameters = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"Email\":\"%@\"}",_TxtMail.text]  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
        options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
        error: &e
    ];

   [manager POST:@"http://www.unluapps.com/Service1.svc/CheckRejected" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       // NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        _receivedData=responseObject;
        //NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject objectForKey:@"CheckifExistsResult"]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject objectForKey:@"CheckRejectedResult"]);
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    ];
```

Comment: This url http://www.unluapps.com/Service1.svc/CheckRejected is not get response . 404 error

Comment: i already said i'm using POST in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i spent hours on the code, i found another method and also that the link of the web service is case sensitive.I've changed the code and now it's working. If you are using microsoft products on the server side please be careful not to do the mistakes i made.

The Code:

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:@"http://www.unluapps.com/Service1.svc/checkRejected"
       parameters:@{@"email": _TxtMail.text}
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
           NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject objectForKey:@"CheckRejectedResult"]);

          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager uses AFHTTPRequestSerializer by default. Add

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer new];
```

After AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's initialisation.

Also you can simplify your code:

```
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer new];
   NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"Email": _TxtMail.text};

   [manager POST:@"http://www.unluapps.com/Service1.svc/CheckRejected" parameters:parameters   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       // NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        _receivedData=responseObject;
        //NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject objectForKey:@"CheckifExistsResult"]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject objectForKey:@"CheckRejectedResult"]);
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    ];
```

Comment: status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 11;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Mon, 14 Jul 2014 08:55:45 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.unluapps.com/Service1.svc/CheckRejected, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}

Comment: how can i set content type as text html

Comment: Thanks for the help, i found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one helps you

You are using AFHTTPRequestOperation and not AFJSONRequestOperation.

Also you can use the AFHttpClient directly:

```
NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"Email":self.email.text};
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[httpClient postPath:@"http://www.unluapps.com/Service1.svc/CheckRejected" parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Print the response body in text
    BOOL *success = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self handleConnectionError:error];
}];
```

I would also suggest creating a creating only one instance of the AFHTTPClient using clientWithBaseURL: method.
Also read the documentation on [github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) it does explain how to correctly use the AFHTTPClient. Have a look at the AFAppDotNetAPIClient this will give you a good example on how to use the AFHTTPClient.

Comment: fails to build: unknown type name 'AFJSONRequestOperation'

Comment: check this link https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking it will help you to change from 1.0 to 2.0

Comment: Thanks for the help, i found the solution.